# Вывод переменой на LineEdit

Tags: qt

Имеется следующая задача:
Необходимо вывести переменную data из функции fun1() на форму в LineEdit. При нажатии кнопки выполняется fun1() и текущая должна выводиться  data. Заранее благодарен за помощь!
Листинг программы:

```
main.cpp

#include <QApplication>
#include "fun1.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>

void fun1(void)
{
   int i,j;
   int data=1;

   for (i=1;i<100;i++)
   {
       for (j=1;j<10000;j++)
       {

       }

      data+=1;
   }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   MainWindow w;
   w.show();
   return a.exec();
}`

mainwindow. cpp

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "fun1.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
   : QMainWindow(parent)
   , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
   ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
   delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   fun1();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
int fun1(void)
{
   int i,j;
   int data=1;

   for (i=1;i<100;i++)
   {
       for (j=1;j<10000;j++)
       {

       }

      data+=1;
   }
return data; // или как надо форме реультат сказать?
}
...
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   ui->LineEdit1->setText(QString("%1").arg(fun1()));
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Однако в LineEdit выводится только конечное значение data. Есть ли возможность получать data на каждой итерации ( чтобы в LineEdit data изменялась от 1 до 100) ?